# OpenVPN configure: error: lzo enabled but missing

Tags: networking, dependencies, vpn, openvpn

openvpn-2.4.8
https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.4.8.tar.gz
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I want to Build and Install OpenVPN.

```
tar -zxf openvpn-<version>.tar.gz
cd openvpn-<version>
./configure
```

I get the following output:
`configure: error: lzo enabled but missing`

Trying to install lzo yields the following.

```
sudo apt install liblzo2-2
liblzo2-2 is already the newest version (2.08-1.2).
```

How can I install a version of lzo which is recognized by the ./configure script?

Answer (score 41):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev
```

solved it for me. Thank you https://dietervansteenwegen.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/installing-openvpn-on-ubuntu-12-04/ .